# GMail Access Token Expired for each one hour, refresh token not working

Tags: php, google-api, google-oauth, gmail-api

I have a token.json file from oauth authentication to access gmail api,

```
{
   "access_token":"token",
   "expires_in":3599,
   "refresh_token":"token",
   "scope":"https:\/\/mail.google.com\/ https:\/\/www.googleapis.com\/auth\/gmail.compose",
   "token_type":"Bearer",
   "created":1615956208
}
```

Below I have include my code

```
Class Connection extends CI_Controller {
    public function __construct() {
        // echo .'contruct';
        // die;
        // parent::__construct();
        $this->credentials = "assets/gmail_api/credentials/credentials.json";
        $this->client = $this->create_client();
    }

    public function get_client() {
        return $this->client;
    }
    public function get_credentials() {
        return $this->credentials;
    }
    public function is_connected() {
        return $this->is_connected;
    }
    public function get_unauthenticated_data() {
        $authUrl = $this->client->createAuthUrl();
        return "<a href='".$authUrl."'>Click to  Link Your Gmail</a>";
    }
    public function credentials_in_browser() {
        if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    public function create_client() {
        $client = new Google_Client();
        $client->setApplicationName('Gmail API PHP Quickstart');
        $client->setScopes(array(
            'https://mail.google.com/',
            'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.compose'
        ));
        $client->setAuthConfig($this->credentials);
        $client->setAccessType('offline');
        $client->setPrompt('consent');

        // Load previously authorized token from a file, if it exists.
        // The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
        // created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
        // time.
        $tokenPath = 'assets/gmail_api/'.$_SESSION['mail_box_email'].'/token.json';
        if (file_exists($tokenPath)) {
            $accessToken = json_decode(file_get_contents($tokenPath), true);
            $client->setAccessToken($accessToken);
        }

        // If there is no previous token or it's expired.
        if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
            // Refresh the token if possible, else fetch a new one.
            if ($client->getRefreshToken()) {
                $client->fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken($client->getRefreshToken());
            }
            elseif ($this->credentials_in_browser()) {
                $authCode = $_GET['code'];
                // Exchange authorization code for an access token.
                $accessToken = $client->fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode($authCode);
                $client->setAccessToken($accessToken);

                // Check to see if there was an error.
                if (array_key_exists('error', $accessToken)) {
                    throw new Exception(join(', ', $accessToken));
                }
            }
            else {
                $this->is_connected = false;
                return $client;
            }
            // Save the token to a file.
            if (!file_exists(dirname($tokenPath))) {
                mkdir(dirname($tokenPath), 0700, true);
            }
            file_put_contents($tokenPath, json_encode($client->getAccessToken()));
        }
        else {
            $this->is_connected = true;
            return $client;
        }
        $this->is_connected = true;
        return $client;
    }

}
```

Here i have refresh token to,

I have search about oauth access token, it always expires in 1 hour, but i want to extend this time as much long is possible, so i use refresh token, here my token.json file has refresh token, but still it's expire in one hour, i have read google oauth documentation, they said refresh token maximum life time is 200 days ( https://cloud.google.com/apigee/docs/api-platform/antipatterns/oauth-long-expiration ),

How can i increase the life time of access token, really i can't understand how it's work, please give some solution about extend the access token life time

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Access tokens expire after an hour this is standard in all authorization servers.  This is not something you can change.

What you should do is use the refresh tokens to request a new access token whenever you need one.   Refresh tokens for the most part do not expire,  however there are some tricks with gmail api scopes,  if the user changes their password it will expire.

```
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token
client_id={ClientId}&client_secret={ClientSecret}&refresh_token={refreshtoken}&grant_type=refresh_token
```

You shouldn't need to deal with any of this if you are using the php client library all of this should be handled for you.

## [Oauth2Authentication.php](https://github.com/LindaLawton/Google-APIs-PHP-Samples/blob/master/Samples/Gmail%20API/v1/Oauth2Authentication.php)

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
/**
 * Gets the Google client refreshing auth if needed.
 * Documentation: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2
 * Initializes a client object.
 * @return A google client object.
 */
function getGoogleClient() {
    $client = getOauth2Client();

    // Refresh the token if it's expired.
    if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
        $client->fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken($client->getRefreshToken());
        file_put_contents($credentialsPath, json_encode($client->getAccessToken()));
    }
return $client;
}

/**
 * Builds the Google client object.
 * Documentation: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2
 * Scopes will need to be changed depending upon the API's being accessed.
 * Example:  array(Google_Service_Analytics::ANALYTICS_READONLY, Google_Service_Analytics::ANALYTICS)
 * List of Google Scopes: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/googlescopes
 * @return A google client object.
 */
function buildClient(){
    
    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setAccessType("offline");        // offline access.  Will result in a refresh token
    $client->setIncludeGrantedScopes(true);   // incremental auth
    $client->setAuthConfig(__DIR__ . '/client_secrets.json');
    $client->addScope([YOUR SCOPES HERE]);
    $client->setRedirectUri(getRedirectUri());  
    return $client;
}

/**
 * Builds the redirect uri.
 * Documentation: https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/auth/installed-app#choosingredirecturi
 * Hostname and current server path are needed to redirect to oauth2callback.php
 * @return A redirect uri.
 */
function getRedirectUri(){

    //Building Redirect URI
    $url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];                    //returns the current URL
    if(strrpos($url, '?') > 0)
        $url = substr($url, 0, strrpos($url, '?') );  // Removing any parameters.
    $folder = substr($url, 0, strrpos($url, '/') );   // Removeing current file.
    return (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? "https" : "http") . '://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $folder. '/oauth2callback.php';
}


/**
 * Authenticating to Google using Oauth2
 * Documentation:  https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2
 * Returns a Google client with refresh token and access tokens set. 
 *  If not authencated then we will redirect to request authencation.
 * @return A google client object.
 */
function getOauth2Client() {
    try {
        
        $client = buildClient();
        
        // Set the refresh token on the client. 
        if (isset($_SESSION['refresh_token']) && $_SESSION['refresh_token']) {
            $client->refreshToken($_SESSION['refresh_token']);
        }
        
        // If the user has already authorized this app then get an access token
        // else redirect to ask the user to authorize access to Google Analytics.
        if (isset($_SESSION['access_token']) && $_SESSION['access_token']) {
            
            // Set the access token on the client.
            $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['access_token']);                 
            
            // Refresh the access token if it's expired.
            if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {              
                $client->fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken($client->getRefreshToken());
                $client->setAccessToken($client->getAccessToken()); 
                $_SESSION['access_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();              
            }           
            return $client; 
        } else {
            // We do not have access request access.
            header('Location: ' . filter_var( $client->getRedirectUri(), FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
        }
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        print "An error occurred: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
}
?>
```

## [oauth2callback.php](https://github.com/LindaLawton/Google-APIs-PHP-Samples/blob/master/Samples/Gmail%20API/v1/oauth2callback.php)

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
require_once __DIR__ . '/Oauth2Authentication.php';

// Start a session to persist credentials.
session_start();

// Handle authorization flow from the server.
if (! isset($_GET['code'])) {
    $client = buildClient();
    $auth_url = $client->createAuthUrl();
    header('Location: ' . filter_var($auth_url, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
} else {
    $client = buildClient();
    $client->authenticate($_GET['code']); // Exchange the authencation code for a refresh token and access token.
    // Add access token and refresh token to seession.
    $_SESSION['access_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
    $_SESSION['refresh_token'] = $client->getRefreshToken();    
    //Redirect back to main script
    $redirect_uri = str_replace("oauth2callback.php",$_SESSION['mainScript'],$client->getRedirectUri());    
    header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect_uri, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
}

?>
```

Comment: if user change his password after it expiring is not my problem, but how can i use refresh token?

Comment: The code i gave you is the actual call to use a refresh token and get one back an access token.    As you didnt post your code i cant tell you how to use it in your code.  If you are using the PHP client library then this might help https://github.com/LindaLawton/Google-APIs-PHP-Samples/blob/master/Samples/Gmail%20API/v1/Oauth2Authentication.php

Comment: i have edited my question with my question sir, Thank you for patience

Comment: Looks like you already are using the refresh token.

Comment: but i expires with in one hour sir, mostly i have completed all gmail api integration, finally i have stuck with this one

Comment: The access token expires the section where you have **if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {** will fetch a new access token using a valid refresh token.

Comment: my refresh token also refresh with in one hour sir, my token.json file valid only for 2hours, i want to know about how to extend the refresh token life.

Comment: Refresh tokens **don't** expire its good for more then two hours.  BTW I am not a sir.

Comment: ok @DalmTo, i have check out your youtube videos to, so my refresh token don't done it's work, how can i use that in proper way do you have any sample codes for this,
and then i have a another query need to clarify from you, how to get total email counts based on label id?

Comment: Try the two files i just posted. that's the sample code i do have for Gmail api.  it shows how to work with the refresh tokens but it stores them as session vars.  You could also store them in your database along with the user id so you know whos refresh token it is.

Comment: @DalmTo, i find what i miss in my code

if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
        $client->fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken($client->getRefreshToken()); // i do fetch access token with refresh token,
        file_put_contents($credentialsPath, json_encode($client->getAccessToken())); //  but i don't  put the content in credential path..
 }

Is that correct? 

and what is credentials path is that we download from oauth creadential list ?

Comment: $client->setAuthConfig(__DIR__ . '/client_secrets.json');  <--- the credentials you download from Google developer console.    What you are trying to store is the user credentials, a refresh token associated with a user.